# AngularJS validation issue in select when using a button, but not when using a span

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation

In my code for select validation

```
<span class="error" ng-show="mainForm.businessprocess.$error.required && submit">required</span>
```

and in the controller I have

```
$scope.submit=function(){
    $scope.submit=true;
}
```

If I click on the button then the popup shows like normal HTML validation and Angular's validation is not working.

Here is a JSFiddle for the same:
http://jsfiddle.net/priya78/nF7eJ/65/

If I remove the button and use

```
<span class="error" ng-show="mainForm.businessprocess.$error.required ">required</span>
```

then Angular's validation is working.

I want to show required in red text on click of button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. Add `novalidate` to the `<form>` tag
2. Rename the boolean `submit` property because you already have assigned this name to a function
3. Functions must be called explicitly (`ng-click="click()"`)

Final version: http://jsfiddle.net/nF7eJ/67/

Comment: after clicking on submit button i am calling a webservice and after success callback i am again resetting value of select to "" bt doing that creates error message required.

Comment: @PriyaBhatt set `$scope.submitted` to `false` when you're resetting the value of the select.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function `submit`. In your code you forgot the parenthesis and javascript will not call the function but treat it as a function pointer. Updated [code](http://jsfiddle.net/nF7eJ/66/).

```
<button ng-click="submit()">Apply Now</button>
```

Comment: but then also popup is coming there. i want to stop that popup

Comment: use `novalidate` o nthe form tag :)